# Fetching row from SQLite database consumes 100% of processor time

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

Here is DDL script we got for a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [stat_ping] (
  [lid] INT NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 
  [ping] NUMERIC(6, 2) NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 
  [timeping] DATETIME NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

Data sample for table:﻿

```
lid ping    timeping
2036    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2002    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2006    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2015    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2009    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2000    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2016    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2031    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2016    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2018    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2012    1   2013-02-26 10:46:27.000
2008    1   2013-02-26 10:46:28.000
2019    1   2013-02-26 10:46:29.000
2001    0   2013-02-26 10:46:29.000
2005    1   2013-02-26 10:46:29.000
113     1   2013-02-26 10:46:30.000
```

We compute a percent of availability of services by that data using such query:

```
lock (Logger._lockObj)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection sql = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLite"].ToString()))
    {
        sql.Open();
        foreach (var item in kk)
        {
            item.ping.stconn = 0;
            string sqlquery = "select (sum(s.ping)*100/count(s.timeping)) from stat_ping as s where s.timeping between datetime('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','-1 day') and datetime('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "') and s.lid=" + item.lid;
            using (SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand(sqlquery, sql))
            {                                
                item.ping.stconn = Convert.ToByte(comm.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We use Devart SQLite data provider for connectivity. Table stat_ping contains about 100000 rows. So for 5 items it takes about 6-7 seconds for calculating percent and takes 100% processor.

I know what we should use separate stored procedure for calculating percent for all items for just one invoking of stored procedure/function, but could anyone share about real performance and using opportunity experience?

Another one my project will use SQLite database as container for SOAP message logging. I think database can take a lot of space, as just one pair of request and response takes 150KB.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using some index to speed up your query?
I also would propose to use prepared and parameterized query, because it's quite heavy to generated new command in a loop.

Also, from my experience, SQLite database it quite slow when there're a lot of rows in a table. We used to clean up SQLite database of older data, we archived it into another database.

BTW, MS SQL Server CE (it's embedded in-proc database, no setup is required) behaves just perfect when there're a lot of data in a table. We used in as a caching database for Windows service which dealt with several thousands of clients. It starts to slow down when database size grows over 1GB.

Comment: Yes, I have an index on lid column. It takes faster on time (with index), but still quote slow and 100% of processor. Could you please describe how do you make archiving of older data? How many rows in table do you have?

Answer (score 0):

To execute queries, the SQLite engine certainly needs CPU time, that depends on query complexity too. dotConnect for SQLite calls functions of the sqlite3.dll engine and then this engine defines the required amount of resources including CPU time. The fact of using the required CPU time is a normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You say you only have an index on your `lid` column – but you are filtering your data by `timeping` here:

```
 string sqlquery = "select (sum(s.ping)*100/count(s.timeping))
   from stat_ping as s where s.timeping between
   datetime('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','-1 day')
   and
   datetime('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')
   and s.lid=" + item.lid;
```

– so try an additional index on `timeping`.

And I also notice that you are doing this query for several `lid` here in a loop. Maybe it would be more efficient to try and get all that data with *one* query, GROUPing by `lid`? (Dropping the current last WHERE condition, of course. Or if you want data not for all `lid` entries in the table but for just a few select ones, then add a `and s.lid IN (…,…,…)` condition.)